# Gnome Boxes in Ubuntu: Can't leave Fullscreen mode

Tags: virtualization, gnome-boxes

I'm running Gnome Boxes in Ubuntu 16.10 to virtualize Windows XP, but when I press the fullscreen button, the only way to go back to the host is to power off the virtual machine.

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

OBS: I've installed the SPICE guest for Windows.

Comment: From here https://www.lifewire.com/guide-to-gnome-boxes-2202073 *There is an icon with a double arrow in the top right which toggles between full screen and a scaled window.*

Answer (score 3):

With Ubuntu 19.10 and Gnome Boxes 3.32 you have two possible solutions to exit fullscreen mode:

1. When you move your mouse to the top of the screen a bar should pop up: Press the third icon to the right to exit full screen mode.
2. Press and release (left) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to ungrab keyboard. Then you can use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to another window in your host system.

Comment: This also  works for `Gnome Connections` which seems to be based on `Gnome Boxes`